# Why does the JDK have both Math.random() and the Random class?

Tags: random, java

Is it just because of "large API syndrome" or generating random numbers that are more biased favored in some situations?  If it was..I would think that controlling the bias-ness would be important.

Comment: What you mean bias-ness I guess is: 1) uniform distribution (you have as many hits in (0.2 to 0.3) as in (0.5 to 0.6)) and 2) the numbers are independent from one another (not quite true, but it looks as such).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're the same, really. Just a convenience method. Check the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29). Additionally, you're able to re-seed by creating random objects, while `Math.random()` will use a static Random instance.

Comment: Almost always want to use Random as you can control seeding and generate various types (boolean, int, etc.).

Comment: Please don't link to the JavaDocs for an obsolescent JRE, I updated the link to point to the v. 7 docs.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - seems like this is an area where the StackExchange code could be improved and report bad links to users who make them?

Comment: @djangofan OT: It's an area where Oracle should action the RFE I raised that puts the 'latest' [javadocs at a constant URL](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  :(   Failing that, I've considered asking SE for a custom 'tag'/ element whatever along the lines of `[javadoc:java.lang.Math.random()]` and have the translation done at SE servers.  *But getting a constant URL would be optimal.*

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for fixing, I didn't realize the link was outdated. Note taken, and, can we support your RFE somewhere?

Comment: To support the RFE/Bug ID.  1) Establish an account with Oracle (free, but tortuous).  2) Log-in and vote for the RFE (one of the lower links in the left column).  It currently has 4 votes, but maybe if we can push that to 10, the priority will be elevated from **5-Very Low**!